# VisitMethodCall not visiting every part

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have an expression visitor translating the expression to a url format. But it only converts the expression called at last. For example, if I call my collection like this:

```
NetworkAccountStorage.Where<NetworkAccountModel>(x => x.ID + 1 > 0).Select(x => x.Name).Distinct()
```

Distinct would be the only expression visited. How to solve this?

```
protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
    {
        if (m.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable) && m.Method.Name == "Where")
        {
            sb.Append("$filter=");
            //this.Visit(m.Arguments[0]);
            //sb.Append(") AS T WHERE ");
            LambdaExpression lambda = (LambdaExpression)StripQuotes(m.Arguments[1]);
            this.Visit(lambda.Body);
            return m;
        }
        else if (m.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable) && m.Method.Name == "Select")
        {
            sb.Append("$select=");
            LambdaExpression lambda = (LambdaExpression)StripQuotes(m.Arguments[1]);
            this.Visit(lambda.Body);
            return m;
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The method '{0}' is not supported", m.Method.Name));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to recurse. Distinct takes a `this` parameter which is the .Select call etc.

Comment: But what Property has to be recursed?

Comment: The expression that is bound to the first parameter of Distinct. Sadly I have no example lying around and no time to make one

Comment: found it. I just had to visit Arguments[0]

Comment: @MarcoKlein I recommend that you do not manually visit everything. Take a look at my answer. This thing is automated for you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to recurse by calling the base method that you overrode:

```
base.VisitMethodCall(...);
```

Comment: So you think this would be correct?

m = m.Update(m.Object, m.Arguments);
return base.VisitMethodCall(m);

Comment: Modifying m has no effect - it is a local variable (a parameter). It is your private copy. Try this (and if it doesn't work right away, you need to fix it somehow): `return m.Update(base.Visit(m.Object), m.Arguments.Select(x => base.Visit(x)));`. Not sure what you call `Update` for but it must have a reason.